# php use regex with mb_split to achieve str_split functionality with UTF8

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to split a string into an array.
I've tried str_split() but the problem is that characters like "äüöÄÜÖß" don't work (they become questionmarks)

So I'm trying to do the same with mb_split(), but I don't know how to get the right Regex for it.

Can you please help me?

Here is the code:

```
$arr = mb_split("\.", $str);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try:

```
$arr = preg_split('//u', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

For the `/u` modifier, see http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php :

*"u (PCRE8) This modifier turns on additional functionality of PCRE that is incompatible with Perl. Pattern strings are treated as UTF-8. This modifier is available from PHP 4.1.0 or greater on Unix and from PHP 4.2.3 on win32. UTF-8 validity of the pattern is checked since PHP 4.3.5."*

Comment: I want to get an array like ["w", "o", "r", "d"] out of "word"

Comment: You're right, but I did get you started in the right direction! I've updated my answer, per your suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

ok. that's it:

```
$arr = preg_split('//u', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```